# how do i change mvc views from the controller?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have the razor view add_event.cshtml:

```
 @model InputEvent

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyEvent"))
 {
     inputs
     ...
     ...
     ...
     <input type="submit" value="Save" />
 }
```

with the post controller here:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Save(InputEvent y)
 {

     ...
     ...
     ...
     return View()
}
```

I want to return to a specific URL with return View(). I have tried putting the string in for the url: `return View("App/page")`. but the url that i am taken to every time is "/MyEvent/Save". This URL doesnt even exist.

How do get to the view of a specific url?

EDIT: thanks. i had tried that before but i switched the two strings up

Comment: Replace `return View()` with `return RedirectToAction("yourActionMethod", "yourControllerName");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try redirect if this is an option for you.

```
return RedirectToAction("SomeView", "Home");
```

Also passing a model should do. I have

```
return View("SomeView", someViewModel);
```

in my code and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RedirectToAction()`

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName","ControllerName");//OR return RedirectToAction("ActionName","ControllerName", routevalue);
```

[Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx)